# Variable 'target' was declared with 'integer' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series[float]'

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking to get the single highest value for the previous 5 bars of data but keep running into the posted error:
`Variable 'target' was declared with 'integer' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series[float]'.`

Here are the 2 lines of code in question:

```
var target = 0
target := highest(high, 5)[0]
```

I would assume this would retrieve the latest highest value but it instead returns a series. Please let me know the correct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a .0 after var target. The highest function is looking for a float variable.

var target = 0.0

Alternately we could forgo using var at all here and just say = highest().

Also we do not need [0] as that references this bar which it will do anyway. We can place 1 or more in there to reference one bar back etc.

Cheers my friend and best of luck with your trading and coding

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's right that Pine didn't like that the variable was an integer rather than a float